# How to "git push" on remote machine

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I use git with an account on BitBucket for software I develop at work. At home I login to my work computer via ssh. On the remote computer I can do `git add` and `git commit`, but `git push` and `git pull` give me this error:

```
Permission denied (publickey)
```

I do not get this error if I am physically at my work computer. How can I do `git push` and `git pull` on my work computer without being physically there?

Comment: Are you SSHing in as the same user account that you use directly?  Do you have agent-forwarding enabled?

Comment: Yes I am using the exact same account. I am not familiar with agent-forwarding. I will look it up.

Comment: I added `ForwardAgent yes` in `~/.ssh/config` for `Host @bitbucket`. It does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

That message comes from `ssh`.

You need to import your public ssh key into your BitBucket account.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `ssh` key of your machine into your Bitbucket account setting.

You can generate the ssh key using

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@domain.com"
cat id_rsa.pub
```

copy the output of last command and paste it "Bitbucket -> Bitbucket account setting -> ssh key -> add key"